# Multithread concurrency and load error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

I wrote a simple application to test multiple threads' concurrent access to model/database in Rails.

I created a model Counter, and it has an integer attribute "count".

Then I have a script that creates 3 threads which concurrently read the current value of `count` of the first `Counter` in the database, which is 11. Here is the code:

```
 1   def func(index)
 2    puts "[thr#{index}] this is #{Thread.current}"
 3    i = 0;
 4    while i < 5
 5      puts "[thr#{index}] #{Time.now} #{index}.#{i} read count = #{Counter.first.count}"
 6      i += 1
 7      sleep(1)
 8    end
 9   end
10
11   ###loc_A###
12   puts "[main] started At #{Time.now}"
13
14   all_threads = []
15   1.upto(3) do |index|
16    all_threads << Thread.new{func(index)}
17    ###loc_B###
18   end  
19   all_threads.each { |t|  t.join }
20
21   puts "[main] end at #{Time.now}"
```

I always get a `LoadError` exception in `active_support/dependencies.rb` like this:

```
04:32 PM ~/app/test_multithread $ rails runner script/multithread.rb 
[main] started At 2012-02-13 16:33:03 -0800
[thr1] this is #<Thread:0x00000100e1b288>
[thr2] this is #<Thread:0x00000100e1b0a8>[thr3] this is #<Thread:0x00000100e1aef0>

[thr1] 2012-02-13 16:33:03 -0800 1.0 read count = 11
[thr1] 2012-02-13 16:33:05 -0800 1.1 read count = 11
[thr1] 2012-02-13 16:33:06 -0800 1.2 read count = 11
[thr1] 2012-02-13 16:33:07 -0800 1.3 read count = 11
[thr1] 2012-02-13 16:33:08 -0800 1.4 read count = 11
/Users/whk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:490:in `load_missing_constant': Expected /Users/whk/Development/rails_projects/test_multithread/app/models/counter.rb to define Counter (LoadError)
    from /Users/whk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
    from /Users/whk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
    from /Users/whk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
    from script/multithread.rb:5:in `func'
    from script/multithread.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thread1 runs to completion, but it seems like the second thread [thr2] hits LoadError when accessing the model Counter and exits, and likely the same happened to the third thread.

Now, if I access the model before the threads by adding this line

```
puts "[main] #{Counter.inspect.to_s}"
```

at `#loc_A`, then all three threads run to completion successfully.

```
04:36 PM ~/app/test_multithread $ rails runner script/multithread.rb 
[main] Counter(id: integer, count: integer, ts: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
[main] started At 2012-02-13 16:36:57 -0800
[thr1] this is #<Thread:0x000001016410e8>
[thr2] this is #<Thread:0x00000101640f08>[thr3] this is #<Thread:0x00000101640e40>
[thr1] 2012-02-13 16:36:57 -0800 1.0 read count = 11

[thr2] 2012-02-13 16:36:57 -0800 2.0 read count = 11
[thr3] 2012-02-13 16:36:57 -0800 3.0 read count = 11
[thr1] 2012-02-13 16:36:58 -0800 1.1 read count = 11
[thr2] 2012-02-13 16:36:58 -0800 2.1 read count = 11
[thr3] 2012-02-13 16:36:58 -0800 3.1 read count = 11
[thr1] 2012-02-13 16:36:59 -0800 1.2 read count = 11
[thr2] 2012-02-13 16:36:59 -0800 2.2 read count = 11
[thr3] 2012-02-13 16:36:59 -0800 3.2 read count = 11
[thr1] 2012-02-13 16:37:00 -0800 1.3 read count = 11
[thr2] 2012-02-13 16:37:00 -0800 2.3 read count = 11
[thr3] 2012-02-13 16:37:00 -0800 3.3 read count = 11
[thr1] 2012-02-13 16:37:01 -0800 1.4 read count = 11
[thr2] 2012-02-13 16:37:01 -0800 2.4 read count = 11
[thr3] 2012-02-13 16:37:01 -0800 3.4 read count = 11
[main] end at 2012-02-13 16:37:02 -0800
```

Or if I insert a delay between the creation of each thread by adding this line

```
sleep(1)
```

at `#loc_B`, all three threads also run to completion.

The problem seems to be related to the loading of the model. If the model is prefeteched, or given time to load, then the LoadError doesn't happen. Is the model loaded once for all threads, loaded individually for each thread? Can anyone explain this to me?

My environment is

- sqlite3
- Rails 3.1.1
- ruby 1.9.2p290

Comment: The problem seems to be related to this Ruby bug #921 "Autoload is not thread-safe": http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/921. The fix is targeted for version 1.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the autoload issue in ruby. Autoload is no threadsafe. You can resolve this by adding *require* statements.

I faced a similar issue in my Rails app. And I solve the issue using eager loading the modules I required for threads.